How to respectfully pray unto Nila Sarasvati for Her departure after attempting to invoke Her?
To solve a problem, two months ago, for about 2 or 3 weeks, I did some Puja to Nila Sarasvati, but without ever having been started to his practice, and without even knowing who she really was.
So now I am energetically vampirized by Nila Sarasvati, the symptoms are weakness, lack of energy, headache and mental confusion.
I later became aware that she is fierce and thirsty for blood.
In reality, a divination warned me that I would have had vampirism problems evoking her, but I believed the card in question wanted to indicate another thing, instead it indicated precisely energy vampirism of the goddess.
I did not understand why I was bad, I did many clinical tests and everything was in order, so I questioned the cards and came out that it is Nila Sarasvati to cause me this.
The question is: how do I definitively move she away?
P.S. Currently, I practice the Puja in Green Tara with the acting of the 21 Lodi in Tara and this allows me to be a little better, but if I stopped for a few days the symptoms would become much stronger.
In the last few days I have also practiced repentance (for having evoked Nila Sarasvati) I will eager to do so.

divinatory cards, but not tarot

Are you certain that Devi's unhappiness is causing you trouble or is it your hallucination? if you're, surrender to her completely with utmost humility by words, action (by bowing down), and thought. One cannot simply 'send away' the divine shakti  after invoking them through a Mantra as they're not our servant. Also, never do it again without guidance of a Guru.

Invoking the deity is called Avahana and asking her to go away is Udvasan or Visarjan .. both these techniques have to be learnt from the Guru before starting a formal worship. @CaneRandagio

@Harihara I updated the original thread with an update, please read it and give me your precious opinion.

@Rickross Thanks for the contribution, in fact I suffer from impatience and sometimes I throw myself without first inquiring me well. By now the omelette has been done, and we just have to serve and eat it, I can't adjust the eggs.

Happy to know that it worked. By surrendering to Her, rest assured that Her energies will not affect you in any bad way. But I do not know what the divination is which you're referring to. If it is not based on Hinduism, unfortunately I cannot comment on it. Kindly do not combine Vedic practices with others for your well-being as they're highly potent in themselves. Meditating totally in the mind should be fine but uttering certain Mantras or worshipping a Yantra externally will require guidance, ideally from a teacher who is awakened.
